# Rails 5: Fastest way to fetch huge records in select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cocoon-gem

I have a Rails application which loads more than 2k registers from a model on a select with [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) for association. I'm already use select2 jQuery plugin to scroll it and search the topics, but it loads very slowly.

```
<%= f.select :subject_id, options_for_select(Subject.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id, {}] }, f.object.subject_id), {include_blank: 'Select a subject'}, {required: true, class: "select2 "} %>
```

This model load more than 2k registers from model and makes select load slowly, what's is the best practice to load the register more quickly from model for user?

Comment: Scroll-pagination and simple search in your select box?

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing that, the question is about to load the registers from model

Comment: I don't understand your question then, maybe you should rephrase it so it is more descriptive?

Comment: Yes, done, thank you

Comment: So you loading 2k items into select. I would recommend to create search input requesting data via ajax
https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax
https://select2.org/searching#limiting-display-of-the-search-box-to-large-result-sets

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a javascript plugin such as Select2, which will enable you to search through your associations with a remote ajax call. You can see Select2 ajax in action here https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax.

Then, you'll need to initialize select2 in javascript and make sure your registers controller responds to json (you should also paginate these results, with e.g. the Kaminari gem).

Any time you are adding a reference to an association that may contain many records, you'd want to use this remote method for selecting the records.

If you find that you have many associations that need this same remote lookup behavior, you can use a gem such as SimpleForm to help make a reusable [custom input](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Adding-custom-input-components) that handles setting up this behavior for you.

Comment: Are you loading all 2k records at once, or do you paginate through them as you search with select2? If you aren't paginating, you should look into Kaminari, or use a  `limit` with the search to avoid loading that many records at once.

Comment: Loading all records into select2 with search, after load the select2 gets slowly

Answer (score 0):

You should never load 2k records at once from the DB, your data has to be paginated/limited per request. You will have Ruby performance issues (memory issues) and your JS will perform very bad.

One possible solution is to move the records from your SQL to Redis. Because Redis is faster. Then fetch the data from Redis.

To handle large data sets in Select2 follow this plnkr: http://embed.plnkr.co/db8SXs/preview

Comment: Along with all things mentioned above, you should select only those fields which are required for the dropdown to select box load. `Subject.select(:name, :id)`

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution with parameters of Select2. I made it start the search only after type at last 3 digits. This way it not be slow anymore with a huge of data.

```
$(".select2").select2({
          width: '100%',
          placeholder: 'Start ',
          minimumInputLength: 2,
          tags: true
        });
```